# Swift package manager Swift UI view initialization access level issue

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create a swift package for my user interfaces so I can share them between different platforms.

I made the `View` implementation public and added them to my package.

When I try to initialize the view and add as `rootView` for `UIHostingController` I get the error that the initialization access level is internal and I cannot initialize.

I am wondering if there is any way to make this accessible.

Comment: Can we see some code? Maybe try making the view's `init` public?

Comment: @RPatel99 the code sample is not going to be any different than a regular ContentView for example. Yes I tried public init() {} method and as soon as I do this, the SceneDelegate never displays the content view. So I am not sure why that happens. I will try few more things later, but if someone has already come across this would love to hear from them.

Comment: I got that error when implementing a framework I made, and making `init` public fixed it for me. Make sure you are making the `init` for the view you are trying to construct public, and not one of the other views because I initially made that mistake as well.